# Logic Apps subfolder triggers

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a logic app which should copy a file from Box storage to azure blob storage whenever files get updated. I have 4 vendors which will place the files into 4 different folders.

Could you please help me to design a solution for this scenario, As I tried I could create a single trigger for single folder. I am not sure how to create 4 triggers to 4 different files.

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, azure logic app doesn't support trigger by multiple folders in one flow. We can just choose one folder in the trigger and when the files in this folder be modified, the flow will be triggered. Even if you choose the parent folder of the four folders in the trigger, it will not be triggered when the files in subfolder be modified.

As a workaround, we just need create 4 same logic apps with different folders set in the trigger. The logic app is billed by the count of logic app runs triggers, action and connector, so creating four logic apps will just lead to creation headaches but the cost will not increase.